# Save as new record in edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Views: _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
    <% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
      <% f.submit "Save As New" %>
    <% end %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

In my products controller I have all the new,create,edit & update actions normally defined.

**Question:** This form update is working fine but I have a new submit button called "Save As New" is it anyway possible to invoke a create action inside the edit products page, when a user clicks on that.

I know the possibility to use a condition and check if params[:commit]=="Save As New" and try to invoke another action but I am not really sure if I can do that. How should I update my controller to make it work.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the update action like this:

```
if params[:commit]=="Save As New"
  @product = Product.create(params[:product])
else
  @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
end
redirect_to @product
```

So you wont need a new action and can handle it without adding routes...

Comment: yeah, his way is better :)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding it correctly, you want the user to be able to create a new record from inside in the edit page, right?

If that's the case, I think you can do this:

```
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
    <% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
      <%= link_to "Save As New", {controller: 'products', 
                  action: 'new'
                  },
                  class: "if there's a css class"} %>

    <% end %> 
</div>
```